# Size height for item collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

What is the way to set the equal size height for all cells in collection view?

I have this method:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return getCellSize()
  }

  func getCellSize() -> CGSize {
    let screenWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let spaceBetweenItems: CGFloat = CGFloat(2) * 10
    let width: CGFloat = (screenWidth - 10 - spaceBetweenItems) / CGFloat(3.0)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(140.0))
  }
```

And these are my customs cell constraints: 
[image]
[image]

This is my actual output:
[image]

What is wrong in my code or is missing one constraint ?

Comment: Are you missing `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate?

Comment: @son No, I added UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Comment: You need to remove the bottom constraint of your label, that cell won't resize according to your label content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create Constraint CollectionViewHeight.

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and then, try this Code.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let height = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
    collectionViewHeight.constant = height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard with collection view: select your collection view -> go to size inspector -> change field "Estimate size" from "automatic" to "none"
[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi5T2.png).
But then if you text will be too large it will be clipped with dots like "Some large text..", so you can change field "Autoshrink" of your UILabel in attribute inspector to "Minimum Font Scale".